# Understanding structs in C

Tags: c, struct

I just started learning C.

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void func(struct Foo foo){
    foo.x =1;
    foo.array[3] =2;
}

int main(){
    struct Foo lol;
    lol.x = 55;
    lol.array[3] = 67;

    func(lol);
    printf("lol.x is %d and lol.array[3] is %d\n", lol.x, lol.array[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it I get the following errors

```
structs.h:3:22: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct Foo'
void func(struct Foo foo){

structs.h:10:13: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct Foo'
struct Foo lol;
```

I looked it up and a lot of times the problem is in not defining structs in .h file. I defined it in a separate .h file, didnt help. I defined structs on the top of .c file, same errors.

I added this to the top of the file:

```
typedef struct Foo{
int x;
int array[3];
}Foo;
```

Can someone explain why its happening?

Comment: Yup, looks like Foo isn't defined in the code you posted...  can you add the code where you define it?

Comment: How did you define struct Foo?

Comment: Did you `#include` the header that `struct Foo` is defined?

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29 if you aren't sure how to define a struct in C

Comment: Can you show how you attempted to declare the struct?  What was in the `.h` file?  What did you stick at the top of that C file that didn't work?

Comment: You didn't define the structure. If you say you did in a separate header file, you didn't `<#include>` that header file in the code you've posted. You can't use the type `struct Foo` if the compiler doesn't know what `struct Foo` means.

Comment: Looks like a PEBCAK error to me.

Comment: You must to define your strucure before the function where you use it. For instance,  `struct Foo {int a; int b;};`

Comment: @Romaldowoho That compiles & runs for me (after putting the struct definition at the top of the file)

Comment: @Buddy So I moved that to the separate .h file and now it compiles with some warnings. But when I try to run the exe it says Permission denied. Can it be a part of the bug?

Comment: That sounds like a new and different problem.  What OS & compiler are you using?

Comment: @Buddy Im running gcc on Mac Yosemite

Comment: @Buddy i tried doing chmod +x  on it, but it just says cannot execute binary file

Comment: Hmm.. if you're on a Mac, then it shouldn't be making an exe file...  what's the output of `file <executable>` (replacing with your executable's name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I looked it up and a lot of times the problem is in not defining structs in .h file. I defined it in a separate .h file, didnt help.

If you defined struct in separate `.h` file that you should include that file in this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "your_file.h"
....
```

From edit some other problem (**UB**)-

```
foo.array[3] =2;  //you can't access index 3, declaration in struct is  int array[3].
```

Comment: I edited the post to show what I added in .c file. Does it make a difference if I define it at the top of .c or in the separate .h file?

Comment: @Romaldowoho  Yes , it does. If it is `.h` file you want to use it in this `.c` file you need to include it in `.c` file . But if it is defined let say at top of `.c` file then you don't need to do anything . What you have will work.

Comment: That compiles now. Thank you, for some weird reason I HAD to move it to a separate .h file. However when I run exe it gives me Permission denied. Do you know why it can do that?

Comment: OK I GOT IT GOSH. Im sorry this whole thing was all wrong because I wrote the code in .h file initially, then moved definitions to .h files as well, of course it was confused. And then when I compiled it it couldnt execute binary file because I compiled .h file. Sorry. And thank you

Comment: @Romaldowoho  It happens :)

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing  a compilation time error, since **struct Foo foo** cannot evaluate the type. You have to declare the structure before using it.

You can include the header file or just write the following lines above **func definition.**

```
struct FOO
{
    int x;
    int array[n]; // n>3
};
```